# Testing ember js with mocha?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, mocha.js

I'm using `lineman` with `testem`, `ember`, and `mocha+chai`.

I want to test `ember`.  So far, because of how the test scripts and test pages are handled, I can visit a page and test it's contents.

The test page looks like

```
------------------------
Loop through mocha test cases

------------------------

Ember App View




------------------------
```

However, when I try to test for stuff outside of the content like page title:

```
describe('testing page title', function () {
    it('should equal ember-template', function () {
        visit('/');
        find('title').text().should.equal('ember-template');
        find('title').length; // this is 0
    });
});
```

it gives me an error of

```
✘ expected '' to equal 'ember-template'
    AssertionError: expected '' to equal 'ember-template'
```

How do I test `ember` completely with `mocha`?

Comment: It would seem to me like the root page has no title or you are trying to get it before the page is fully loaded

Comment: @c0d3junk13 I know for sure that the page has a title, but your second hypothesis seems to make sense. I'm not sure how `ember` tests work so I don't know if the `visit` and `find` are executed `async` or not.

Answer (score 2):

`visit()` is asynchronous, whereas `find()` is synchronous (it's just a jquery selection under the hood), so the transition to the page likely isn't finished by the time you check the title. The `andThen()` test helper will wait for the preceding async activity to finish before executing a callback. Try the following:

```
describe('testing page title', function () {
    it('should equal ember-template', function () {
        visit('/');
        andThen(function() {
            find('title').text().should.equal('ember-template');
            find('title').length; // this is 0
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: hmmm... tried this and got the same error. `AssertionError: expected '' to equal 'ember-template'`

Comment: to clarify, if you navigate to '/', and enter `$('title').text()` in the console, is 'ember-template' returned? I'm not sure that's valid jquery, which could explain why the above is failing. Assuming you're trying to get the window title, I think valid jquery would be `$(document).attr('title')`. Also, I just noticed that the `find()` helper is specifically scoped to the app's root element, so if the title is outside of that, you'll need to use jQuery to select it and run an assertion on that instead of the Ember helper.

Comment: yes, `$('title').text()` does return 'ember-template'.

Comment: ok, since the `find()` helper is scoped to the app's root element (and if I understand correctly, 'title' is outside of that scope) what happens if you change the assertion to `$('title').text().should.equal('ember-template');`?

Comment: `AssertionError: expected 'Test\'em' to equal 'ember-template'`, the result compares the testing page's title when it should be comparing the ember page's title.

Comment: Not sure there's a great way around that, since Testem changes the page title, and there's no option to make it not do that. https://github.com/airportyh/testem/issues/195 If it's an important test, sounds like you'll need to use something other than Testem.

Comment: I use `testem` because it's very easy to use, works across many browsers, and integrates well into my workflow.  Can you please recommend some other test frameworks that can test cases like a document's title, and are as user/dev friendly as `testem`?

Comment: To be honest I can't really help you there. It's a pretty different question than your original one so maybe post a new question specifically for that. Sorry I could only get you halfway there!